# upload button does not render how I wish vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I've cannot understand why the upload button is not in a new line;

this is my code
(copied mostly from vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-upload)

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ApplicationLayout extends VerticalLayout implements View {   

    public ApplicationLayout() {
        
        
        ImageUploader receiver = new ImageUploader();
        Upload upload = new Upload(null, receiver);
        upload.setButtonCaption("Inizio Upload");
        upload.addSucceededListener(receiver);
        
        final HorizontalLayout uploadInfoLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        uploadInfoLayout.addComponent(upload);
        
        addComponent(uploadInfoLayout);
        
    }
```

This is how is it looks like now:

[image]

Is there a way to put the button "Inizio Upload" below the text, like in the following picture:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you show all code and the styling?

Comment: the code for the receiver is in https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-upload; the style is what vaadin has set to default; I haven't modified the style; If you need to see the style file inside src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/exercisestheme ; I can send but it has more than 13000 lines